# Sewer debris backflowing in basement toilet and tub when washer drains

Tags: plumbing

In the last few days, the basement toilet started bubbling when the washer (basement too) start draining water.

But since yesterday, sewer crap started backflowing in the toilet and tub that us next to it.

It happened last year, and a plumber used a machine to get roots off the main line in the clean out. But it just like that suddenly and it was back flowing everytime we were using anything water related in the house. The plumber removed a bunch of tree roots and it worked fine afterward.

Back to today, it does pretty much the same thing as last year but only when the washer drains water near the end of the cycle. I can use the faucet next to the toilet and let it run for a while and no bubbles in the toilet. Really only happene with the washer draining process.

Can it still be related to the main line? Or does it sound more like the washer drain pipe has an blockage or issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your washer drain to a utility sink?

Comment: No I don't have a utility sink. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount and rate of water being drained from the washing machine *far* exceeds that which you'll get out of the faucet, so it's not surprising that you're not having issues from a sink. Yet...

I had a similar issue, but with a toilet backing up regularly. I rented a snake to clean out the line myself a couple of times with minimal success. I finally hired a plumber to do it. He did a much better job than I did and had the drains running freely.

His recommendation, since he pulled a lot of roots out, was to use a root killer product specifically designed to prevent roots from growing back into the drain lines.

I used a product that I found at my local big-box home improvement store. They claimed that a single series of treatments would do the trick. I was not interested in having the plumber come back, so I ran two series of treatments as prescribed and haven't had a single problem since.

I'd suggest that you *might* need to have it snaked again. You *may* however be early enough in the root regrowth process that applying chemicals may be sufficient. I'd suggest giving chemistry a try (since it doesn't cost very much), and if that doesn't work, give a plumber a call again. If you do have to call a plumber back, do another series of treatments (or two) after he's gone and that will *likely* be the end of your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any products in particular you would recommend? Also, I just tried it and running the bath tub for around 30 seconds will make the toilet bubbles. Does it change anything?

Comment: Nope, product recommendations are off-topic here. Particularly since I don't have a clue where you live and what products are available there. Just hit up your local retailers to see what's on the shelf. Mine was little granules that I flushed down the toilet as the last thing at night and let them soak overnight. I'm sure others are similar. Issues from the tub just indicate that the blockage _is_ getting worse - it causes issues with higher flows for now but will, eventually, block up the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I rented a snake to clean the line myself too, and it went great. I managed to remove a bunch of roots once again (really thin ones, but a lot of them).  Weird that a plumber did it last year, and they came back that fast. Now I'll try to find a product to prevent roots from getting in there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nope, not at all weird that they're back that fast, @larin555. There's _some_ sort of crack/break/access that the tree has found and it'll find it again very quickly considering the large quantity of nutrient rich water passing through your drain line. Your only option is to kill (by cutting or chemical) the roots near your drain. You could reroute the sewer line, but that's a bit, um... _extreme_ :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a partial clog somewhere *past* where the washer drain and the toilet and tub connect to the sewage line. Presumably the toilet is the lowest possible output point. Washer draining is by far the fastest drain in the house, particularly if you have an old-style top loader (like I have) which uses a lot of water. A dishwasher only uses a few gallons at a time. Toilets a couple of gallons quickly but then nothing until the next flush. Most other outputs are limited by the input, so typically no more than 2 or 3 gallons per minute. But a large washer might hold 20 gallons (that's based on a quick search that says 40 gallons per load, which would be split in two for wash and rinse cycles) and push that all out in 2 or 3 minutes. The end result is that a partial clog that has no effect on other usage can overflow when the washer drains.

The causes can include:

- Roots
- Toys or other objects flushed down the toilet
- Accumulated lint, grease and hair
- Broken pipes

For lint, grease and hair, chemicals will usually help. Unfortunately, with a partial clog the chemicals might pass through too quickly and have little time on the clog to do their work. There are some chemicals recommended specifically for roots, but I don't know how effective they are. The gold standard is mechanical cleaning, which for a main line often means a big machine either with a plumber using it or yourself renting it. I have used the big machine myself once successfully, and another time with a handyman successfully. I have had limited success with smaller machines (which I've bought, and which work fine for individual sink or tub drain clogs) and chemicals.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I might try to rent a machine first, it's around 90 bucks where I live. Is your clean out outside or in your basement? I'm wondering if opening the cleanout trap will brin a ton of water in.

Comment: I have a floor drain in the basement, so that's both where stuff comes out and where I snake through. The catch is that I always have trouble getting past the trap - I am horrible at this stuff! There is a cleanout in a vertical pipe but I've never used it. What the pros do is pull off the basement toilet (in my case that is next to the front of the house, so for roots definitely the best place to start). Advantage of starting with toilet is that you don't have to deal with a trap. The disadvantage is the hassle of taking off and putting back the toilet - for the pros that's no big deal but

Comment: for me that's a lot of work. Plus if the clog is before the toilet (sometimes in my case, but in your case clearly the clog is *after* the toilet) then the starting at the toilet wouldn't do any good. As far as the official cleanout, I doubt you'll get tons of water because you only have a partial clog.

Answer (score 0):

Feeder roots form a fine net that trap small debris and hold dirt. They also seek the moisture in the ground.  When a line is power rodded like you had last year it cuts these feeder roots back to clear the line and they typically just start growing again the next day.  Depending on the tree species, size, etc it is possible that they grew back.  I don't know where you live but they can come back in one spring/summer cycle.
Typically people get away with two years.
Unfortunately the best option is to replace the line with Sewer and Drain PVC.  Which is expensive.
Its possible you have another issue though.  Does it happen when you do a large load of laundry, drain a bathtub, or take a long shower?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried it and running the bath tub for around 30 seconds will make the toilet bubbles. Does it change anything?